# formatting to two decimal places and 1 sig fig

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to format a double into a string of two decimal places and 1 sig fig. My code so far is below, am I doing it correctly?  Or should I not be creating a temporary string?...

```
// sets rounding to two decimal places
DecimalFormat format_calculated_reported_concentration = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

// removes grouping seperators e.g. 1,000 becomes 1000
format_calculated_reported_concentration.setGroupingUsed(false);

/// rounds
String temp_calculated_reported_concentration =
       format_calculated_reported_concentration.format(calculated_concentration);

// applies the pattern of 1 significant figure only to the decimalformat
format_calculated_reported_concentration.applyPattern("@");

// 1 sig fig
calculated_reported_concentration = 
       format_calculated_reported_concentration
            .format(Double.valueOf(temp_calculated_reported_concentration));
```

Comment: Just a note, your variables are using an underscore to separate words, but the java convention is to use camelCase.  E.g., `format_calculated_reported_concentration` should be `formatCalculatedReportedConcentration` instead.

Comment: I want something like 0.006 to become 0.01 (2 decimal places, and 1 sig fig)

Comment: the range of values is 0.005 to < 0.1

Comment: Sorry what i meant is that the value 0.006 first needs to be rounded to two decimal places and then only get 1 sig fig

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this work?

```
// sets rounding to two decimal places
DecimalFormat format_calculated_reported_concentration = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

// removes grouping seperators e.g. 1,000 becomes 1000
format_calculated_reported_concentration.setGroupingUsed(false);

// applies the pattern of 1 significant figure only to the decimalformat
format_calculated_reported_concentration.applyPattern("@");

// 1 sig fig
calculated_reported_concentration = 
       format_calculated_reported_concentration
            .format(calculated_concentration);
```

You could also set up the `DecimalFormat` once, like in a constructor or initializer, rather than every time you do the formatting.